# download file from localhost

Tags: php, html

I want to put an image on my web and when clicked it will download a specific file. is this the correct script for this purpose ? but when I click there is no response.

```
<td><a href="file:download/D411.zip"><img src="images/download.png" title="Download"></a></td>
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="download/abc.zip" download>Download link here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `download` folder is in the same directory from where you are executing this snippet.

Change

```
<a href="file:download/D411.zip">
```

to

```
<a href="download/D411.zip">
```